# How to show 40 gabor filter in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filter

can someone help me how to show gabor filter in matlab, i can show it but its not what i want. this is my code :

```
 [Gf,gabout] = gaborfilter1(B,sx,sy,f,theta(j));


G{m,n,i,j} = Gf;
```

and this is gabor filter class:

```
function [Gf,gabout] = gaborfilter(I,Sx,Sy,f,theta);

if isa(I,'double')~=1 
    I = double(I);
end

for x = -fix(Sx):fix(Sx)
    for y = -fix(Sy):fix(Sy)
        xPrime = x * cos(theta) + y * sin(theta);
        yPrime = y * cos(theta) - x * sin(theta);
        Gf(fix(Sx)+x+1,fix(Sy)+y+1) = exp(-.5*((xPrime/Sx)^2+(yPrime/Sy)^2))*cos(2*pi*f*xPrime);
    end
end

Imgabout = conv2(I,double(imag(Gf)),'same');
Regabout = conv2(I,double(real(Gf)),'same');

gabout = sqrt(Imgabout.*Imgabout + Regabout.*Regabout);
```

Then, I imshow with this code:

```
imshow(G{m,n,i,j},[]);
```

and the results :

[image]

But i want this result, can someone help me how to slove this?

[image: gabor filter]

Comment: I think you'll need to post more of your code for us to help. For example, you show the `gaborfilter` function but not the `gaborfilter1` function. Are they the same? I assume you are running `gaborfilter1` inside a loop, can you post that code? I also suspect your formula for the Gabor filter is wrong. Where is sigma? What do you intend `f` to do?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following function. I hope this is useful.
    ----------------------------------------------------------------

```
gfs = GaborFilter(51,0.45,0.05,6,4);
n=0;
for s=1:6
   for d=1:4
        n=n+1;
        subplot(6,4,n)
        imshow(real(squeeze(gfs(s,d,:,:))),[])
   end
end
```

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fIan.jpg)
    ----------------------------------------------------------------

```
function gfs = GaborFilter(winLen,uh,ul,S,D)

% gfs(SCALE, DIRECTION, :, :)

winLen = winLen + mod(winLen, 2) -1;
x0 = (winLen + 1)/2;
y0 = x0;

if S==1
    a = 1;
    su = uh/sqrt(log(4));
    sv = su;
else
    a = (uh/ul)^(1/(S-1));
    su = (a-1)*uh/((a+1)*sqrt(log(4)));
    if D==1
        tang = 1;
    else
        tang = tan(pi/(2*D));
    end
    sv = tang * (uh - log(4)*su^2/uh)/sqrt(log(4) - (log(4)*su/uh)^2);
end

sx = 1/(2*pi*su);
sy = 1/(2*pi*sv);
coef = 1/(2*pi*sx*sy);

gfs = zeros(S, D, winLen, winLen);

for d = 1:D
    theta = (d-1)*pi/D;
    for s = 1:S
        scale = a^(-(s-1));
        gab = zeros(winLen);
        for x = 1:winLen
            for y = 1:winLen
                X = scale * ((x-x0)*cos(theta) + (y-y0)*sin(theta));
                Y = scale * (-(x-x0)*sin(theta) + (y-y0)*cos(theta));
                gab(x, y) = -0.5 * ( (X/sx).^2 + (Y/sy).^2 ) + (2*pi*1j*uh)*X ;
            end
        end
        gfs(s, d, :, :) = scale * coef * exp(gab); 
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the "cos" component by complex part->`complex(0, (2*pi*f*xprime))` ans also multiply equation by scaling factor of `(1/sqrt(2*Sy*Sx))`.