# Need explanation about Filter Gabor

Tags: image-segmentation, fingerprint, biometrics

I am studying a finger recognition system.
There are so many algorithms.
If I write it with my own words, one of the algorithm (especially about minutiae-based binarized image) will consist of the following steps:

STEP1. Segmentation. This step to separate the foreground from the background. Most done with Thresholding.

STEP2. Normalization. This step to distribute the intensity. Most done with Histogram Equalization.

STEP3. Filtering. This step to fill the gap along the ridge. Also to enhance the contrast between the ridge and the valley. Most done with Gabor Filter.

STEP4. Binarization. This step to binarize the filtered image.

STEP5. Thinning. This step to skeletonize the binarized image.

STEP6. Minutiae Extraction. This step to extract minutiae (ridge ending and ridge bifurcation) from the skeletonized image.

STEP7. Minutiae Matching. This step to match between extracted minutiae template and extracted minutiae input.

I still not understand about STEP3 especially related Gabor Filter.
I really need step-by-step explanation about Gabor Filter.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

The Gabor filter is in fact a collection of filters. Each filter has a modulated Gaussian function as convolution kernel. The difference between each filter is the orientation. See an example [here](http://www2.it.lut.fi/project/simplegabor/downloads/laitosrap100.pdf) page 17, [here](http://journal.frontiersin.org/article/10.3389/fnins.2015.00137/full) section 2.2.2, or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255068/how-to-show-40-gabor-filter-in-matlab). Each filter is applied to the image, and the maximum answer is kept.

As each filter may have an elongated shape with a specific direction, and because you keep the maximum answer, the gabor filter will:

1. Find (thin) oriented patterns, like lines, edges, etc. (see page 17 too)
2. Reconnect discontinued lines. Indeed, the middle of the kernels will be between the lines, but the filter with the good orientation will have both extremities touching the lines. You can also do such operation with mathematical morphology (oriented opening/closing).

Here are other examples:

1. [link](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2085/image-de-noising-with-better-edge-preservation).
2. [link](http://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/7/7/8779/htm).
3. You should [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878754/how-to-convolve-an-image-with-different-gabor-filters-adjusted-according-to-the).
4. [Is that not what you want to do](http://hristoalexiev.blogspot.com/p/computer-vision.html)?